# PHP - How to maintain the order of the array when foreach the array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm with  trouble maintaining the order of the array when processing a foreach.

The original array is the variable `$status`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 [name] => name 11 [order] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => name 4 [order] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 12 [name] => name 12 [order] => 3 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => name 5 [order] => 4 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => name 6 [order] => 5 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 7 [name] => name 7 [order] => 6 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => name 9 [order] => 7 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => name 8 [order] => 8 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [id] => 10 [name] => name 10 [order] => 9 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => name 1 [order] => 10 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => name 2 [order] => 11 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => name 3 [order] => 12 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [id] => 13 [name] => name 13 [order] => 13 ) 
)
```

Now when I foreach this array:

```
    foreach ($status as $item)
    {
        if(!isset($report['status'][$item['id']]))
        {
            $report['status'][$item['id']] = Array();
        }
    }
```

I got this:

```
Array (  
    [status] => Array ( 
                [1] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 2 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 5 ) 
                [4] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 3 
                        [2014-05-05] => 147 
                        [2014-05-06] => 10 
                        [2014-05-07] => 9 
                        [2014-05-08] => 7 ) 
                [5] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 20 
                        [2014-05-06] => 2 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 10 ) 
                [6] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 1 
                        [2014-05-05] => 2 
                        [2014-05-06] => 2 
                        [2014-05-08] => 2 ) 
                [7] => Array (  
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 14 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 4 ) 
                [8] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 1 
                        [2014-05-05] => 8 
                        [2014-05-08] => 1 ) 
                [9] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 8 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 4 ) 
                [10] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 8 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 1 ) 
                [11] => Array ( ) 
                [12] => Array ( ) 
                [2] => Array ( ) 
                [3] => Array ( ) 
                [13] => Array ( ) 
    ) 
)
```

But what I need to have is this:

```
Array (  
    [status] => Array (
                [11] => Array ( ) 
                [4] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 3 
                        [2014-05-05] => 147 
                        [2014-05-06] => 10 
                        [2014-05-07] => 9 
                        [2014-05-08] => 7 )
                [12] => Array ( ) 
                [5] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 20 
                        [2014-05-06] => 2 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 10 )
                [6] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 1 
                        [2014-05-05] => 2 
                        [2014-05-06] => 2 
                        [2014-05-08] => 2 ) 
                [7] => Array (  
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 14 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 4 ) 
                [9] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 8 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 4 ) 
                [8] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 1 
                        [2014-05-05] => 8 
                        [2014-05-08] => 1 ) 
                [10] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 8 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 1 ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                        [2014-05-02] => 2 
                        [2014-05-05] => 2 
                        [2014-05-06] => 1 
                        [2014-05-07] => 1 
                        [2014-05-08] => 5 )  
                [2] => Array ( ) 
                [3] => Array ( ) 
                [13] => Array ( ) 
    ) 
)
```

So, my question is, how can I maintain the order of the original array $status?

Best Regards,

Comment: How are those dates making it into your data set? I don't see them in the original

Comment: Foreach loops over the keys in the order they were added. If you're adding elements to your array in a strange order that's the first place I'd check for a clean solution, rather than adopting any sort of work around to "fix" the issues being seen here.

Answer (score -1):

Why not keep the first index, that should make it easier

```
foreach ($status as $key => $item)
    {
        if(!isset($report['status'][$key][$item['id']]))
        {
            $report['status'][$key][$item['id']] = Array();
        }
    }
```

You do have an extra layer but you can ignore it if you want.